# Extension pattern in a flask controller using importlib 2.0

Tags: python, flask

The first edition of the code can be found in [this 1.0 version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96533/extension-pattern-in-a-flask-controller-using-importlib).

To summarize the problem :

- I have an endpoint in flask where the work logic change according to the query
- I am trying to implement an extension mechanism where the right class is loaded
- The first version did not provide caching of the imported class

Based on the answer from @netme, this is a code update where I lazy load the right handler class and cache it :

**./run.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, abort
import handler

app = Flask(__name__)

handler_collection = handler.HandlerCollection()

@app.route('/')
def api_endpoint():
    try:
        endpoint = "simple" # Custom logic to choose the right handler
        handler_instance = handler_collection.getInstance(endpoint)
    except handler.UnknownEndpoint as e:
        abort(404)

    print(handler_instance, handler_instance.name)
    # Handler processing. Not yet implemented

    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

**./handler.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import importlib

import handlers

class UnknownEndpoint(Exception):
    pass

class HandlerCollection:
    _endpoints_classes = {}

    def addClass(self, endpoint_class):
        self._endpoints_classes[endpoint_class.name] = endpoint_class

    def getClass(self, endpoint_name):
        if (endpoint_name in self._endpoints_classes):
            return self._endpoints_classes.get(endpoint_name)

        try:
            # Try to import endpoint handler from a module in handlers package
            endpoint_module = importlib.import_module(
                '.{}'.format(str(endpoint_name)),
                'handlers')
            endpoint_module.register(self)
        except ImportError as e:
            raise UnknownEndpoint('Unknown endpoint \'{}\''.format(endpoint_name)) from e

        return self._endpoints_classes.get(endpoint_name)

    def getInstance(self, endpoint_name):
        endpoint_class = self.getClass(endpoint_name)
        return endpoint_class()
```

**./handlers/simple.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class SimpleWebhookHandler:
    name = "simple"

def register(handler_collection):
    handler_collection.addClass(SimpleWebhookHandler)
```

Each handler needs to provide a `register` function which allows to have different handler class name and each handler class needs to provide a class attribute `name`.

Can you give me your opinion on this piece of code ? Is it "pythonic" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you give me your opinion on this piece of code ? Is it "pythonic" ?

I don't really see anything non-pythonic about it.
Some minor coding style issues though:

- Minor [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations:

  - put 2 blank lines before `class` and top-level function definitions
  - use `snake_case` for function names instead of `camelCase`
- Unnecessary parentheses in `if (endpoint_name in self._endpoints_classes):`

A bigger issue I see is that the module loading is convoluted and fragile:

- `HandlerCollection.getClass` tries to import a module : violates the single responsibility principle, it would be better to move this logic somewhere else
- The imported module is expected to have a `register` function : a semantic rule, not obvious enough from the code itself. There are no docstrings either, so as it is, implementors have to dig this piece of information out of the current implementation details
- The `register` function must pass a class that has a `name` property defined : semantic rule, see the previous item
- The logical flow of `HandlerCollection.getClass` is convoluted:

  1. try to import module if missing
  2. pass self to `module.register`
  3. `module.register` calls `me.addClass`

  I suggest to move the module loading part out to a different method, perhaps `HandlerRegistry.load_and_register_if_missing`, and let `getClass` behave as a simple cache.

Comment: I don't understand. The 2 first line of the `getClass` method are doing your first note on `endpoint_name`. If you look at the `register` function in the module `handlers.simple`, it registers the handler class in the collection so it won't be `None`. Thanks for pointing out the PEP issues.